# Reshaping a 1-d array to a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, language-lawyer

Taking into consideration the entire C++11 standard, is it possible for any conforming implementation to succeed the first assertion below but fail the latter?

```
#include <cassert>

int main(int, char**)
{  
    const int I = 5, J = 4, K = 3;
    const int N = I * J * K;

    int arr1d[N] = {0};
    int (&arr3d)[I][J][K] = reinterpret_cast<int (&)[I][J][K]>(arr1d);
    assert(static_cast<void*>(arr1d) ==
           static_cast<void*>(arr3d)); // is this necessary?

    arr3d[3][2][1] = 1;
    assert(arr1d[3 * (J * K) + 2 * K + 1] == 1); // UB?
}
```

If not, is this technically UB or not, and does that answer change if the first assertion is removed (is `reinterpret_cast` guaranteed to preserve addresses here?)? Also, what if the reshaping is done in the opposite direction (3d to 1d) or from a 6x35 array to a 10x21 array?

**EDIT:** If the answer is that this is UB because of the `reinterpret_cast`, is there some other strictly compliant way of reshaping (e.g., via `static_cast` to/from an intermediate `void *`)?

Comment: Very interesting question, and I think it may be possible to do this without UB, thanks to "layout-compatible" types, although I'm not sure if those only apply to structs / classes - will have to investigatte.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the C++11 spec _guarantees_ this behavior actually.

Comment: Well, do I need to check the first assertion then, or not? Are the addresses guaranteed to be equal?

Comment: 4.2 An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.  (addresses are guaranteed to be equal)

Comment: yeah, but this is casting between references to two different array types

Comment: @MooingDuck: We're not comparing the address of array to its converted pointer here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update 2021-03-20:**

This same question was [asked on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/m9a7fs/reinterpret_a_1d_array_as_a_2d_array/) recently and it was pointed out that my original answer is flawed because it does not take into account this [aliasing rule](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#basic.lval-11):

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue whose type is not similar to one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object, or
> - a char, unsigned char, or std​::​byte type.

Under the rules for [similarity](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#conv.qual-2), these two array types are not similar for any of the above cases and therefore it is technically undefined behaviour to access the 1D array through the 3D array. (This is definitely one of those situations where, in practice, it will almost certainly work with most compilers/targets)

*Note that the references in the original answer refer to an older C++11 draft standard*

## Original answer:

### `reinterpret_cast` of references

The standard states that an lvalue of type `T1` can be `reinterpret_cast` to a reference to `T2` if a pointer to `T1` can be `reinterpret_cast` to a pointer to `T2` (§5.2.10/11):

> An lvalue expression of type `T1` can be cast to the type “reference to `T2`” if an expression of type “pointer to `T1`” can be explicitly converted to the type “pointer to `T2`” using a reinterpret_cast.

So we need to determine if a `int(*)[N]` can be converted to an `int(*)[I][J][K]`.

### `reinterpret_cast` of pointers

A pointer to `T1` can be `reinterpret_cast` to a pointer to `T2` if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout types and `T2` has no stricter alignment requirements than `T1` (§5.2.10/7):

> When a prvalue v of type “pointer to T1” is converted to the type “pointer to cv T2”, the result is `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))` if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout types (3.9) and the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`, or if either type is void.

1. Are `int[N]` and `int[I][J][K]` standard-layout types?

   `int` is a scalar type and arrays of scalar types are considered to be *standard-layout types* (§3.9/9).

   > Scalar types, standard-layout class types (Clause 9), arrays of such types and cv-qualified versions of these types (3.9.3) are collectively called *standard-layout types*.
2. Does `int[I][J][K]` have no stricter alignment requirements than `int[N]`.

   The result of the `alignof` operator gives the alignment requirement of a complete object type (§3.11/2).

   > The result of the `alignof` operator reflects the alignment requirement of the type in the complete-object case.

   Since the two arrays here are not subobjects of any other object, they are complete objects. Applying `alignof` to an array gives the alignment requirement of the element type (§5.3.6/3):

   > When `alignof` is applied to an array type, the result shall be the alignment of the element type.

   So both array types have the same alignment requirement.

That makes the `reinterpret_cast` valid and equivalent to:

```
int (&arr3d)[I][J][K] = *reinterpret_cast<int (*)[I][J][K]>(&arr1d);
```

where `*` and `&` are the built-in operators, which is then equivalent to:

```
int (&arr3d)[I][J][K] = *static_cast<int (*)[I][J][K]>(static_cast<void*>(&arr1d));
```

### `static_cast` through `void*`

The `static_cast` to `void*` is allowed by the standard conversions (§4.10/2):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv `T`,” where `T` is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv void”. The result of converting a “pointer to cv `T`” to a “pointer to cv void” points to the start of the storage location where the object of type `T` resides, as if the object is a most derived object (1.8) of type `T` (that is, not a base class subobject).

The `static_cast` to `int(*)[I][J][K]` is then allowed (§5.2.9/13):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 `void`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 `T`,” where `T` is an object type and cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1.

**So the cast is fine!** But are we okay to access objects through the new array reference?

### Accessing array elements

Performing array subscripting on an array like `arr3d[E2]` is equivalent to `*((E1)+(E2))` (§5.2.1/1). Let's consider the following array subscripting:

```
arr3d[3][2][1]
```

Firstly, `arr3d[3]` is equivalent to `*((arr3d)+(3))`. The lvalue `arr3d` undergoes array-to-pointer conversion to give a `int(*)[2][1]`. There is no requirement that the underlying array must be of the correct type to do this conversion. The pointers value is then accessed (which is fine by §3.10) and then the value 3 is added to it. This pointer arithmetic is also fine (§5.7/5):

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

This this pointer is dereferenced to give an `int[2][1]`. This undergoes the same process for the next two subscripts, resulting in the final `int` lvalue at the appropriate array index. It is an lvalue due to the result of `*` (§5.3.1/1):

> The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points.

It is then perfectly fine to access the actual `int` object through this lvalue because the lvalue is of type `int` too (§3.10/10):

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object
> - [...]

So unless I've missed something. I'd say this program is well-defined.

Comment: +1 for standard quotes, have to think about your answer though

Comment: this was helpful, had no idea `reinterpret_cast` was actually ok in this case; everything sounds good to me

Comment: Unfortunately, you run afoul of there not being an array on which to do the array-to-pointer conversion.

Comment: *A pointer to `T1` can be `reinterpret_cast` to a pointer to `T2` if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout types and `T2` has no stricter alignment requirements than `T1` (§5.2.10/7).* Why alignment requirement here is specified against types, not pointer values? Can not I cast a pointer to `T2` from `T1` when `T2` has stricter alignment requirement and the pointer is aligned?

Comment: _it is technically undefined behaviour to access the 1D array through the 3D array_ It is not UB, it is impossible, since [access to objects of array type is not a thing](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/defns.access#sentence-2).

Answer (score 1):

I am under the impression that it will work. You allocate the same piece of contiguous memory. I know the C-standard guarantees it will be contiguous at least. I don't know what is said in the C++11 standard.

However the first assert should always be true. The address of the first element of the array will always be the same. All memory address will be the same since the same piece of memory is allocated.

I would therefore also say that the second assert will always hold true. At least as long as the ordering of the elements are always in row major order. This is also guaranteed by the C-standard and I would be surprised if the C++11 standard says anything differently.

Comment: "Taking into consideration the entire C++11 standard,"

Comment: is the behavior of `reinterpret_cast` guaranteed in this case, though? these are technically incompatible types

Comment: @StephenLin "The result is a pointer to the first element of the array"  So the 1d becomes a pointer to the first int.  The 3d becomes a pointer to the first 2d array, which becomes a pointer to the first 1d array, which becomes a pointer to the first int.  The _same_ first int.

Comment: @AxelOmega: I'm not certain "row-major" is the right term for a 3d array.

Comment: @MooingDuck: An array doesn't decay recursively or something.

Comment: @Xeo: if it didn't it would be a compiler error, wouldn't it?  That's the only conversion I know of to get from `int[][][]` to `void*`

Comment: but the point is the `reinterpret_cast`, not the `void *` part. is that guaranteed to preserve the addresses or not?

Comment: @MooingDuck: The C-style cast is doing a `reinterpret_cast`, basically, I think. That can do whatever it wants.

Comment: @Xeo, I think to/from `void *` has some special guarantees on preserving addresses, I might be wrong; I don't think `reinterpret_cast` to/from incompatible arrays does, though, which is why I wrote it this way

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes that is the crux of the question? Maybe I should sleep instead of answering before I can do proper research. And well row major might not be right for 3D but the point I was trying to make was that the right most index varies fastest when traversing consecutive addresses in memory.

Comment: @AxelOmega: Yes, C++ has the same ordering of elements.