# Adding dimension to an array

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to add one or more dimension to an existing array in c++? For example, I have 2 dimensional array, in somewhere I need to add one or more dimension to this array.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what, as poitroae already mentioned, you will need a copy of some sort. This copy however would be sped up a great deal if you simulated 2-D and 3-D arrays with a 1-D array which is why I decided to post an answer in the first place.

In order to simulate 2-D and 3-D arrays with a 1-D array, you can use simple math to index into the array. This lowers memory segmentation making it faster due to having more chache hits. To add a dimension you would simply create another 1-D array with the proper size, and copy in your current data.

I will provide an example when I can find code where I have done this.

**EDIT: Apparently the above is not quite what he wants. I will try again below**

You have: a 1D array simulating a 2D array.

It seems like you do not want to actually add a whole dimension to the array, just the matrix. (basically resizing from one size to another while retaining data)

So, here is an example:

You have a 3x3 (U=3, V=3) matrix below

Logical Representation:

```
|3 5 6|
|7 2 5|
|1 0 2|
```

Physical representation( int[3*3] "matrix")

```
[3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 5, 1, 0, 2]
```

**--Convert to a 4x4(X = 4, Y = 4)--**

```
int* newMatrix = new int[X*Y];
for(int i = 0; i < Y; i++)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < X; k++)
    {
        //copy from old if it falls in bounds
        if(k < U && i < V)
        {
            newMatrix[i*X + k] = matrix[i*U + k];
        }
        //Otherwise, zero out
        else
        {
            newMatrix[i*X + k] = 0;
        }
    }
}
delete [] matrix;
```

That should give you a 4x4 newMatrix.

Logically:

```
|3 5 6 0|
|7 2 5 0|
|1 0 2 0|
|0 0 0 0|
```

Physically:

```
[3, 5, 6, 0, 7, 2, 5, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]
```

If you use variables like I did, you should be able to write a function that will do this
for any matrix as long as you give it accurate parameters (the X and Y dimensions of the matrix)

To go the other way--downsize--it should be a similar set up (double for loop) where you check if you are in bounds and copy over only if you are. And if not, you simply do not copy anything. I will let you write that one.

I hope this is more what you are looking for. I jumped on dimension in the wrong context. Decided to think of an answer more in terms of matrices.

Comment: Actually I don't know exactly how many dimension to add my matrix ahead of time. I will be waiting your example.

Comment: Depending on what kind of data is being given to you, you could figure out the dimensions and create the 1-D array, simply by doing this:
int* matrix = new int[X*Y]; Where X and Y are the dimensions of a XxY matrix

Comment: From there you can index into the array using the width and an offset. I will try to provide an example above as soon as I can.

Comment: But I have already one dimensional matrix representing two dimensional array. This is not what I want. I would like to convert this process to the reverse and in somewhere I will need to add one ore more dimension to my matrix to solve different problem.

Comment: @DeanKnight this isn't what OP wants, I think, but you can actually do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283523/reshaping-a-1-d-array-to-a-multidimensional-array) legally, apparently

Comment: @UgurSahin is the total number of elements changing? if so, you can't get around reallocating: any language that lets you change the size of array is almost certainly reallocating and copying behinds the scenes for you...C++ won't do it for you automatically because it's trivial to do yourself. if the number of elements is not changing but the shape is, you can do what I linked to in the comment above (but I don't think that's what you want)

Comment: Tried putting up another answer. Hopefully that is more what you want? If not, I am not able to help ya. Hope that does it.
@StephenLin Thanks man. Interesting read.

Comment: @DeanKnight I am sorry for my late answer. Thank you for your interest. Actually, maybe this answer works for me I can try it, but literally I want to add a whole dimension to the array. I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: @StephenLin your link seems that i can do this for the three dimensional array but what if i have larger dimension, what should i do? The total number isn't changing, sure, as you said. The only think I want to change is the dimensions of the array. But beforehand I don't know how many dimension i should add. For example, i will need to expand my three dimensional array to the 5 dimension. It depends on the other information coming from the other part of the program.

Comment: @UgurSahin if you don't know how many dimensions you need at compile-time, then how are you going to index the array? it's not impossible, I suppose, but you're going to have to build some kind of dynamic data structure yourself for it...built-in C++ arrays always have a compile-time constant number of dimensions.

Comment: What I am trying to say, when I say I don't know the dimension, is that I can set up static number of dimensions because this depends on the other information, and as you said of course I know at compile time how many dimension I should add. What do you mean to build dynamic data structure? Can you explain a little please?

Comment: @UgarSahin there's no way to have a single variable refer to a built-in array of unknown dimensionality in C++; it has to be statically known at compile-time; if you need that, then you need to create your own class which abstractly handles matrices of different dimensions and overloads `operator[]` to do what you want.

Comment: @StephenLin Thanks for your informative comments. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this implicitly. You have to **create a new array n-dimensional and copy the desired values**

```
int new_array[10][10][10];

// copy using a loop or a std::-function
```