# In which situations reinterpret_cast should be avoided for reshaping arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, embedded, reshape

So I am currently working on an embedded board (STM32) and considering memory constraints in particular, I am trying to avoid heavy functions including memory allocation. I have 1x9 2D array which I need to `reshape` into 3x3. I found it online that it can be done using `reinterpret_cast` but I wonder if it's **safe** to do so?

Below is a sample code that uses `reinterpret_cast` for reshaping as well as normal array operation that I think could be an alternative to `reinterpret_cast`. What do you guys suggest? *check this code: https://repl.it/IIYv/20 ; both have the same outputs*

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

double matrix[1][9] = { {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90} };


//using reinterpret_cast

double (&reshapeMatrix)[3][3]=*reinterpret_cast<double(*)[3][3]>(matrix);
double newArray[3][3];


 int i, j; 

 for (i=0; i<3; i++){
   for (j=0; j<3; j++){
     printf ("%f, ",reshapeMatrix[i][j]);
   }
   printf ("\n");
 }

//using normal array operation
 int r=0, c=0;

 for (i=0; i<3; i++){
   for (j=0; j<3; j++){
     newArray[i][j] = matrix[r][c];
     c++;
   }

 }
 printf ("\n\n\n");

  for (i=0; i<3; i++){
   for (j=0; j<3; j++){
     printf ("%f, ",newArray[i][j]);
   }
   printf ("\n");
 }



}
```

Comment: It is technically UB unfortunately.

Comment: What's UB? @Jarod42

Comment: **U**ndefined **B**ehavior.

Comment: @Doej [Undefined Behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Any behavior not defined by the standard or resulting from violating certain rules.

Comment: What do you mean by "reshape"? 1x9 and 3x3 are just a matter of index calculation. In your case all the fancy nested loops are useless.

Comment: @VTT, similar to matlab's reshape function https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html

Comment: Clang succeeds to warn for a variation of your code [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dc11de4997019ee).

Comment: I think a safe, portable way to do this is to implement a matrix type that stores the data in a flat array.  Then you can reshape it by changing how many rows and columns it represents.

Comment: It's UB, it works (especially on embedded, there is NO sane system that does implement multimiensinal arrays  in non-contiguous way,) it's not safe becase compiler nor runtime not able to detect constraint breach(but on embedded they never can)  and it's ugly. Instead  store matrix as single dimensional array within class with flexible access methods. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283523/reshaping-a-1-d-array-to-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: @NathanOliver Are you referring to the second approach that I used for reshaping?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux but what do you think is wrong with my *second* approach where I am inserting elements in a new array using nested loop

Comment: @Jarod42 what makes it UB?

Comment: What NathanOliver is suggesting is that you don't change the type of your array at all, or copy the contents into a new array. You can simply hide the details of accessing a 1x9 array as a 3x3 array behind a function or method.

Comment: @Rook What's wrong with copying the contents into a new array? It does work completely fine though. Didn't quite what you meant by `hiding` the details?

Comment: @Doej: I would says breaking strict-aliasing rule at least makes it UB.

Comment: The copying is entirely unnecessary. Just write a class that wraps the array, and give it a couple of methods like `get(index)` and `get(row, col)`. No need to copy anything, no need to do potentially UB-invoking casts. Simple, easy to write, easy to read, minimal overhead. What's not to like?